# Using the gamekit to connect to a custom hardware device via bluetooth

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, gamekit

I have a hardware device that broadcasts bluetooth as a serial port.

The device is in production, meaning that there are high financial costs to re-layout a circuit board to include any Apple chip to comply with their "Made for iPhone" program.

So, is there any chance I can use the gamekit api to listen (just need one way comm.) to messages broadcasted by my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None as per my understanding. Assuming you are wanting to talk to a iPhone/iPad/iPod.
Since game-kit is not a standard Bluetooth profile.